# How to stop HTML Source Editor from stripping Google Analytics event tracking code?

Tags: google-analytics, plone

I'm attempting to add the event tracking code (the onClick="gaq.push();" part) to a link's HTML within the content area of a page, using the HTML Source View of the TinyMCE Editor. As soon as I save the page or switch back to the visual editor, the event tracking is stripped from the link's HTML.

In searching, I've found that other CMSs have had to alter their HTML filter settings.

What I'm trying to find out is how can I stop the event tracking code from being stripped without white-listing the  tag, which is a global setting in Plone?

Using: Plone 4.2.1; async GA code has been on site and is working

Answer (score 3):

I think you can configure it under the "hood" a.k.a. in the Zope Management Interface.

1. Go to `Site Setup` and click on `Zope Management Interface`.
   Alternatively, append a `/manage` on the URL if you are on the root
   of your portal.
2. Go to `portal_transforms` and click on `safe_html` in the list of
   transformations.
3. The form should have an item labeled `remove_javascript` which is by
   default set to `1`. Unset this option by setting it to `0`.
4. Save this form by click no `Submit Query`.

A few points to consider to make it finally work:

- You need to flush the object cache and/or restart your Zope server. It is described at the top of the `safe_html` transform.
- TinyMCE won't display the attributes. You need to edit your text without a richtext editor and save your document. You do that by clicking on the `Edit without visual editor` link below the editor on the edit page.
- This **opens up a security risk**. It would be better to implement such a feature as a viewlet and let the viewlet render whenever you need this feature on a page.

Bottom line is: you can enable this, it is risky and there is a better way to achieve this.

Comment: thanks for laying this out. Even though our site does not allow commenting or subscribers, I am still leery of doing something like this.

Comment: Yes. Just be wary of the potential problems it may cause. Jon's answer certainly is the more secure way to go if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

A better way is to use collective.googleanalytics, which uses jquery to inject the extra tags and has a pluggable framework for customizing what gets injected.  This is a safe and extensible way to do this kind of stuff.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks — I read your blog and I've read your entry about this many times. I did install collective.googleanalytics on a test instance a few months ago. But, please correct me if I'm not remembering correctly, it seemed that enabling collective.googleanalytics meant I could no longer view the data through GA website, and this addon requires in depth understanding of metal and tal. Or, maybe I couldn't really test it without interfering with the live site.

Comment: Collective.GA doesn't prevent you from view data in Google Analytics; quite the contrary -- it lets you get more and better data from Plone to Google Analytics (and, yes, also lets you show a little of that data back in Plone, but purely as an optional convenience).

Answer (score 1):

Follow up to romanofski's answer — for anyone who was baffled like me on how to `Edit without visual editor` if that link isn't available. You can go to the `Site setup > Editing control panel` or `http://yoursite.com/@@editing-controlpanel`, temporarily set the default editor to `None`, make the edit on the page or portlet you want the js on, and then switch it back to `TinyMCE`.

Comment: That's an idea. I couldn't get collective.googleanayltics to work. Found js file to track outbound links and added that to javascript registry. Works great! source: [link](http://www.optimum7.com/internet-marketing/web-development/dynamic-google-analytics-event-tracking-for-wordpress.html)